# expand L.control.geocoder above search form

Tags: controls, leaflet, expand, geocode, search-form

I would like to expand the `L.control.geocoder` search form above it and not below it but I couldn't find anything according this problem. 
In my code I display the geocoder form with `collapsed: false` and since this is the default setting, when I enter the search term the results are displayed below the form. Has anyone an idea how to achieve to display the results above the search form?

```
var geocoder = L.Control.geocoder({
    geocoder: new L.Control.Geocoder(),
    collapsed: false,
    placeholder: 'Suchen...',
    errorMessage: 'Leider nichts gefunden'
}).addTo(map);
```